# JS loaded up through Webpack but not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have some custom javascript in my application that toggles the visibility of a password field.  I am adding the javascript in my Rails 6 application through webpacker.

The code seems to import ok (I can see it loaded up in the console) but for some reason it's not executing and I just can't figure out why. Looking online I saw that this might be a scoping issue but I am unsure how to check or how to fix it.

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "../stylesheets/application"
import "bootstrap"
import "../custom/theme"
```

**config/webpack/environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.prepend("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery",
  jquery: "jquery",
  Popper: ["popper.js", "default"]
}))

module.exports = environment
```

**app/javascript/custom/theme.js**
I'm fairly certain that this code is ok. I even added console.logs within the function and those appear in the console without a problem.

```
;(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  const theme = {
    init: () => {
      theme.passwordVisibilityToggle();
    },

    passwordVisibilityToggle: () => {

      let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.cs-password-toggle');

      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        let passInput = elements[i].querySelector('.form-control'),
        passToggle = elements[i].querySelector('.cs-password-toggle-btn');
    
        passToggle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          
          if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') return;
          if (e.target.checked) {
            passInput.type = 'text';
          } else {
            passInput.type = 'password';
          }

        }, false);
      }
    }
  }
  
  theme.init();

})(jQuery);
```

**HTML** Again, pretty sure this is ok but just adding for reference.

```
<div class="input-group-overlay cs-password-toggle form-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend-overlay"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fe-lock"></i></span></div>
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", placeholder: "Password", required: true, class: "form-control prepended-form-control" %>
  <label class="cs-password-toggle-btn">
    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox"><i class="fe-eye cs-password-toggle-indicator"></i><span class="sr-only">Show password</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you rendering the JavaScript in the <head> tag or otherwise before your HTML snippet? If so, you’d want to wrap in an event listener that will run after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @rossta I tried loading it at the end of the body but it still wouldn't work. How would the event listener look like?

Comment: @Aarthi Yes, I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I managed to fix it. At the end I had two do two minor changes:

1. Move the custom JS to a pack under **app/javascript/packs/custom.js** and updated **app/javascript/packs/application.js** to reference the new path.
2. Loaded the javascript at the bottom of the body tag as per @rossta's suggestion.

I tried both of the above separately but they didn't work. It's only when I did both at the same time that it worked.

Hope this helps anyone out there!